# ifelse try combination returns just object of length 1

Tags: json, r, error-handling

if you run this you get info about financial statements

```
library(RJSONIO)
data<-fromJSON("http://www.registeruz.sk/cruz-public/api/uctovny-vykaz?id=4455316",encoding = "UTF-8")
```

when you run this you get vector of length 312 with items from balance sheet

```
data$obsah$tabulky[[1]]$data
```

I am doing this for more companie within loop and sometimes json path above is not present which would return error . So therefore I use try to return NA if there is an error, otherwise I want to just return object from above mentioned path

```
ifelse(class(try(data$obsah$tabulky[[1]]$data))=="try-error",NA,data$obsah$tabulky[[1]]$data)
```

However when I run it it returns just 1 item of vector not full 312

Comment: From `ifelse` documentation: "ifelse returns a value with the same shape as test." If you want to return the whole vector, you could use `if` and `else` separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the result you want from `ifelse` because, per the documentation for that function, "`ifelse` returns a value with the same shape as test." Your test has length 1, so `ifelse` will only return an object with length 1.

To return objects of different dimensions, you can break up the `if` and `else` parts and wrap them in a call to `lapply`. Here's one way to do this, iterating your process over a vector of URLs and collecting the results in a list:

```
lapply(urls, function(x) {

    # you might want try here, too, in case you get errors at this stage
    X <- try(fromJSON(x, encoding = "UTF-8"))

    Y <- try(X$obsah$tabulky[[1]]$data)

    if (class(Y) == "try-error") {

        NA

    } else {

        Y

    }

})
```